# How to deal with compatibility while building game and its levels

Tags: python, pygame, pickle, compatibility

I'm using pygame to make a 3d puzzle game about pushing boxes. The levels take some time to build and I store them using pickle:

```
pickle.dump([level_name,level_size,player,camera,boxes], f, protocol=-1)
```

Here "boxes" is a list of all boxes in the level, these are objects with several attributes and methods.

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z,pushable=True,color=(200,100,50)):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        self.pushable = pushable
        self.color=color

    def draw(self): 
       #....
```

Of course it would be best to finish the game code and then make all the levels, but I want to be able to add game-mechanics as I go.

The problem is that when, for example, I may decide that boxes need to have additional attributes like "visible" and "floating". After I add these properties my new code might say:

```
for b in boxes:
    if b.visible: b.draw()
```

Now my old levels won't work because the pickled version still has the old box-objects lacking the "visible" attribute.

My current solution is to assume all old box-objects are visible, like so:

```
for b in boxes:
    if (not hasattr(b,'visible')) or b.visible: b.draw()
```

However these sort of quick-fixes feel unsustainable as the code grows.

Is there a standard way to deal with these sort of compatibility issues without redoing all the levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it :

I would extend your boxes by using inheritance - so you have standard boxes and enhanced boxes. That way your game can load both (since the original box class still works).

I would also write a method on your enhanced box class that can take an old box object, copy the attributes and return an Enhanced box instance.

Finally I would write a script to load your pickle file with the old boxes, and convert them to the inherited classes, and resave it.

So when you want to extend your box model again - do the same ... and keep going, a new class, and an upgrade script.

When you are finally ready you can refactor and remove the layers of inheritance.